Generating pdfs in next app dont work on deploy why?
I have a problem using jspdf in my next app. In local it works correctly but when I deploy my app in vercel the code below only prints the first doc.text . I don't know why. Thanks for your help.
This is the code I tried.
import { jsPDF} from "jspdf";

function GeneratePDF (){
    const handlePDF = async () => {
        const doc =y new jsPDF("p", "pt", "a4", false);
        doc.text("hello world!", 10 ,10);
doc.text("this does not print in vercel", 10, 20);
        await doc.save("mypdf.pdf");
    }

    return (
        <button onClick={handlePDF}>Generate PDF</button>
    )
} 

